# ActiveSupport::JSON.decode does not properly handle literal line breaks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activesupport

Is this the expected behavior? Note how the line break character gets lost.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > ActiveSupport::JSON.decode("{\"content\": \"active\n\nsupport\"}")
 => {"content"=>"active\nsupport"}
```

The same happens with unicode-escaped line breaks:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 > ActiveSupport::JSON.decode("{\"content\": \"active\u000a\u000asupport\"}")
 => {"content"=>"active\nsupport"}
```

I'm using rails 3.0.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually came across this ticket: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3479-activesupportjson-fails-to-decode-unicode-escaped-newline-and-literal-newlines

It seems this is a bug in ActiveSupport that will be fixed in Rails 3.0.5. For now I have [patched activesupport](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/68e3fb81090ba67575e513407fc2463dba3b002b) and things are working as expected.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > ActiveSupport::JSON.decode("{\"content\": \"active\n\nsupport\"}")
 => {"content"=>"active\n\nsupport"}
```

Comment: Update: This bug appears to still not be fixed in rails 3.0.5.

Answer (score 1):

To represent a newline in JSON data using double quotes, you must escape the newline:

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode("{\"content\": \"active\\n\\nsupport\"}")
```

Otherwise, you are inserting a newline into the JSON *source* and not the JSON *data*. Note that this would also work:

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode('{"content": "active\n\nsupport"}')
```

By using single quotes, you are no longer inserting a *literal newline* into the source of the JSON.

It is interesting to note the way ActiveSupport handles this by default (the default JSON backend is `ActiveSupport::JSON::Backends::Yaml`). By installing the `json` gem and changing the JSON backend to it (`ActiveSupport::JSON.backend = 'JSONGem'`) and attempting to decode the same text (`ActiveSupport::JSON.decode("{\"content\": \"active\\n\\nsupport\"}")`) you get the following:

```
JSON::ParserError: 737: unexpected token at '{"content": "active

support"}'
```

Comment: Thanks Brandon. I don't control the formatting and decoding of the JSON string. It is coming from the client and presented to me in the controller as one of the input parameters. Rails does all the decoding in the background and by the time it gets to the controller, the JSON string has already been decoded into a Ruby object. The patch I mention in my response seems to do the trick for now.